# Discord.js TypeError: user.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey there is my program who send me a message every day at 14:24 :

```
client.once('ready', () => {
client.user.setActivity("WestWorld.", { type: 'PLAYING'})
console.log('Event activate'); 
});    

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const moment = require("moment");
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); 
const request = require("request");

const queue = new Map();
var currentdate = new Date();

asyncevent();

async function asyncevent() {
    console.log('calling');
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
        if ( `${currentdate.getHours()}` === "14" && `${currentdate.getMinutes()}` === "24" ){
            console.log(`${currentdate.getHours()} ${currentdate.getMinutes()}`);
            console.log("MARCHE");
            var user;
            
             user = client.users.fetch('myip')
  
            console.log(`user : ${user}`)
            if(user)user.send("Hey, it's now time");
            wait(60000);
        }
        wait(30000);

    asyncevent();
  }


function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
      end = new Date().getTime();
   }
 }

client.login("MYTOKEN");
```

I don't have the message : "Event connect" so I think maybe I did something wrong and the code don't want to connect to Discord Server.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using discord.js v12 try using `client.users.cache.fetch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```js
user = client.users.fetch('myip')
```

with this

```js
user = client.users.cache.get('myip');
```

Since users.fetch returns a promise, you could also make use of an `await` statement

Comment: Thanks but I have still "user : undefined", and I think it's my code doesn't connect to Discord server... When I add this : client.once('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity("WestWorld.", { type: 'PLAYING'})
    console.log('Event Ready');
}); I have not this message : 'Event Ready')

Comment: @MatDarwin simply move your event after the declaration of your `client` variable